# Identify which country won the most gold, in each olympic games

Tags: python, pandas

When I write the below codes in pandas

```
gold.groupby(['Games','country'])['Medal'].value_counts()
```

I get the below result, how to extract the top medal winner for each Games,The result should be all the games,country with most medal,medal tally

```
Games        country     Medal
1896 Summer  Australia   Gold       2
             Austria     Gold       2
             Denmark     Gold       1
             France      Gold       5
             Germany     Gold      25
                                 ... 
2016 Summer  UK          Gold      64
             USA         Gold     139
             Ukraine     Gold       2
             Uzbekistan  Gold       4
             Vietnam     Gold       1
Name: Medal, Length: 1101, dtype: int64
```

```
    ID  Name    Sex Age Height  Weight  Team    NOC Games   Year    Season  City    Sport   Event   Medal   country notes
68  17294   Cai Yalin   M   23.0    174.0   60.0    China   CHN 2000 Summer 2000    Summer  Sydney  Shooting    Shooting Men's Air Rifle, 10 metres Gold    China   NaN
77  17299   Cai Yun M   32.0    181.0   68.0    China-1 CHN 2012 Summer 2012    Summer  London  Badminton   Badminton Men's Doubles Gold    China   NaN
87  17995   Cao Lei F   24.0    168.0   75.0    China   CHN 2008 Summer 2008    Summer  Beijing Weightlifting   Weightlifting Women's Heavyweight   Gold    China   NaN
104 18005   Cao Yuan    M   17.0    160.0   42.0    China   CHN 2012 Summer 2012    Summer  London  Diving  Diving Men's Synchronized Platform  Gold    China   NaN
105 18005   Cao Yuan    M   21.0    160.0   42.0    China   CHN 2016 Summer 2016    Summer  Rio de Janeiro  Diving  Diving Men's Springboard    Gold    China   NaN
```

Comment: Give an example dataframe, preferrably in text format that is easily loaded here.

Answer (score 3):

The data Your data only included Chinese gold medal winners so I added a row:

```
  ID             Name Sex   Age  Height  Weight     Team  NOC  \
0   17294        Cai Yalin   M  23.0   174.0    60.0    China  CHN   
1   17299          Cai Yun   M  32.0   181.0    68.0  China-1  CHN   
2   17995          Cao Lei   F  24.0   168.0    75.0    China  CHN   
3   18005         Cao Yuan   M  17.0   160.0    42.0    China  CHN   
4   18005         Cao Yuan   M  21.0   160.0    42.0    China  CHN   
5  292929  Serge de Gosson   M  52.0   178.0    69.0   France   FR   

         Games  Year  Season            City          Sport  \
0  2000 Summer  2000  Summer          Sydney       Shooting   
1  2012 Summer  2012  Summer          London      Badminton   
2  2008 Summer  2008  Summer         Beijing  Weightlifting   
3  2012 Summer  2012  Summer          London         Diving   
4  2016 Summer  2016  Summer  Rio de Janeiro         Diving   
5  2022 Summer  2022  Summer       Stockholm   Calisthenics   

                                 Event Medal country  notes  
0  Shooting Men's Air Rifle, 10 metres  Gold   China    NaN  
1              Badminton Men's Doubles  Gold   China    NaN  
2    Weightlifting Women's Heavyweight  Gold   China    NaN  
3   Diving Men's Synchronized Platform  Gold   China    NaN  
4             Diving Men's Springboard  Gold   China    NaN  
5                              Planche  Gold  France    NaN
```

YOu want to de exactly what you did but sort the data and keep the top row:

```
gold.groupby(['Games','country'])['Medal'].value_counts().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).head(1)
```

Which returns:

```
Games        country  Medal
2000 Summer  China    Gold     1
2008 Summer  China    Gold     1
2012 Summer  China    Gold     2
2016 Summer  China    Gold     1
2022 Summer  France   Gold     1
Name: Medal, dtype: int64
```

or as a dataframe:

```
GOLD_TOP = pd.DataFrame(gold.groupby(['Games','country'])['Medal'].value_counts().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).head(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_gold = df[df["Medal"]=="Gold"].groupby("Team").Medal.count().reset_index()
df_gold = df_gold.sort_values(by="Medal",ascending=False)[:8]
df_gold
```